# How do you increase page content?

Tags: pages

I am updating my Terms and Conditions page in the footer of my website and it won't let me add any more words in the back end. As if I have reached my page, word limit. How do I increase this?

Comment: On face value this issues seems a bit unlikely, which suggests there is some aspect of what you are doing that is currently unclear in your question.  Perhaps you could amend it to provide a bit more information about what you are trying to do, which would make working out how to help easier.  Plus it would be useful to know (amongst other things) what version of ExpressionEngine you are using.

Comment: @Joey Your requirement is not fully understandable. Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @jcogs.eecms Just like how this text box to ask and answer questions has a character limit. It seems I have reached the character limit in my page content box and I am unable to add new information. Is there anyway edit these preferences so I can add to the existing content that is there?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should increase the **Maximum characters** limit from **Field Options** of your **textbox** field. By default it set to **256**. You can increase it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like all you need to do is add a new field.  EE supports a broad range of fields you can add to a channel - if currently you are adding text to a 'text' field it as has been noted limited normally to 256 characters.  But there are other field options that support considerably more text - such as "Text Area" or "Rich Text Field".

All you would need to do to take advantage of this is modify the definition of the channel that holds your Terms and Conditions entry to include an additional field - easiest would be to add a 'Text Area' field.  Then update your template for Terms and Conditions to output this field in place of the text field you are using currently (if that is indeed what you are doing) - just find the `{tag}` that outputs the text field currently being used and replace the content between the curly brackets with the short name of the new field.  Finally, open the Terms and Conditions entry in your EE Control Panel and copy over the current text from the Text Field to the Text Area field, and add whatever extra text you need.

HTH